# Why isn’t this JavaScript drawing a rectangle in my <canvas> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Why won’t this work?

```
<html> 
        <head> 
                <title>Learning the basics of canvas</title> 
                <meta charset="utf-8"> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com?/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                        var canvas = $("#myCanvas"); 
                        var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
                        context.fillRect(40, 40, 100, 100); 
                        });
                </script> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
                <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"> 
                        <!-- Insert fallback content here --> 
                </canvas> 
        </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Dunno.  What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is missing a doctype, and there's a typo.

Doctype:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Typo:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com?/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

should be

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
```

Fixed code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
        <head> 
                <title>Learning the basics of canvas</title> 
                <meta charset="utf-8"> 
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
                <script>
                        //<![CDATA[
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                        var canvas = $("#myCanvas"); 
                        var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
                        context.fillRect(40, 40, 100, 100); 
                        });
                        //]]>
                </script> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
                <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"> 
                        <!-- Insert fallback content here --> 
                </canvas> 
        </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a DOCTYPE. Insert `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very top of your page

Comment: I don’t think the doctype is required to get this code working; removing the `?` from the googleapis.com URL seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/VmRVg/

Comment: Yeah, but it's a good thing to add for a browser like IE that would revert to XHTML 4

Comment: @Thomas: `<canvas>`? In IE? Best of luck there.

Comment: @Thomas: and does it require the doctype to work great in IE9?

Comment: I believe so. All i know is when i don't add the doctype, IE9 sticks itself into IE8 mode.

Comment: @Thomas: ah, sure. I’m not seeing that on JSFiddle, but it looks like the site pops the HTML5 doctype into the rendering `<iframe>` itself. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

Add the HTML 5 doctype tag. Many browsers are also still rendering XHTML by default and need you'll need to indicate that this is a HTML 5 format.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: I don’t think any browsers have actual HTML5 parsers turned on yet, and `<canvas>` has been working in some browsers for ages. The code works fine without the HTML5 doctype, [which is there thanks to IE’s quirks mode](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#the-doctype): http://jsfiddle.net/VmRVg/

Comment: That said, as per Thomas’s comments on [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892011/why-isnt-this-javascript-drawing-a-rectangle-in-my-canvas-tag/5892032#5892032), IE 9 will revert to compatibility mode if you miss out one of the doctypes that puts it into standards mode, and will then fail to render `<canvas>` tags.

Answer (score -1):

Try `canvas.getContext('2d')`, without the intervening `get(0)`.

Comment: Downvoted because the `get(0)` (or `[0]`) is necessary to get the DOM `HTMLCanvasElement` out of the jQuery object.

Comment: Still new to jQuery, I'm used to getting it directly using the DOM. Thanks for the info.